# Login with Selenium + Chrome driver + Browsermob Proxy only works if I add another proxy -> why?

Tags: selenium, ssl, selenium-chromedriver, fiddler, browsermob-proxy

I have the code below to initialise a setup of Selenium + Chrome driver + Browsermob Proxy to login to a certain website.

If I just use the setup above, the login fails with HTTP 403. However, if I had another Proxy (Selenium + Chrome driver + Browsermob Proxy + e.g. Fiddler Everywhere, see lines after "to pass requests from proxy server to Fiddler Everywhere") and force the requests from Browsermob Proxy to be proxied by Fiddler Everywhere, then the login works well.

Can anyone provide me a hint on how to debug and/or clear this problem?

I have investigated the headers between all legs:

- "Via: 1.1 browsermobproxy" is being added by Browsermob but I replayed a login request after removing "Via" header from Browsermob, and did not have any effect.
- BrowserMob is removing "Connection:keep-alive". Could this be the cause (or hint at the cause) ?

I also checked:

- The body of the request is not changed across the full chain.
- HTTP protocol version does not change across the full chain (HTTP/1.1).

Here is a detailed log of the request without Fiddler:

```
POST /api/sts/v2/oauth/auth?client_request_id=34634696-b122-40de-b144-ab812a4b3784 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 147
AccountType: Real
X-STS-ClientTime: 2020-08-27T18:10:51
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36
X-STS-AppDomain: https://www.example.com
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-STS-GatewayAppId: 90631448-9A01-4860-9FA5-B4EBCDE5EA1D
ApplicationIdentifier: Rexample
ApplicationVersion: 268.0.1
X-DEVICE-ID: 77f281a4-7914-4417-b144-4811998c3e5b
Origin: https://www.example.com
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://www.example.com/login
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __cfduid=d722b1913f887e5df9b0c740ccef4744a1598548223; exampleLocale=en-gb; TS01047baf=01f1b32d7e1354b9f541c1bab1a81960be72277a638bce5a4865b5b1d5b2e0a9cfddddbcba0d21185b68a7d599391e972d5f065031; __cflb=02DiuEAg8LPSYevHEYiyx9rnANkoz3ETfpNySVtv8fQVr; TMIS2=9a74f2a90237486aab4dcb9d44dec14a0520aaf521b9e87e81f271264e25038c2919d29ee219162aa2ad6bdb68fbe78a86ce282ef510aa77456a3876e4e790d3fdbb0ca31af4d206c67f7b9b5fda93e11b80782ed9095c6a7d8766b4642a69785e7ba9d0a86cd98f3b42c2172a8821bbe6906b6fafc8178f0d742271591193; __cf_bm=50d03de4ce1301af67fa03c59387373fba4d8b3e-1598548241-1800-AZ39AzpjNXxDQ+qFhgfI0OYbMauZ3vXOA1MUejwqJsfE3kOEmEVmKXtsstKg5vZZ5ie/d3yHbgzM8RzzLqqSQEVnd5Vy+l06FUm5Z90kFf54ffUqgq+ywM4EOcGhdP22aetxTezQvFieWgfScPvH0SzqDmFpvrmZJmRuLvnywgcLX14Ys9uA2tMCLWSlDesiQA==; mp_dbbd7bd9566da85f012f7ca5d8c6c944_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2217430e66d1679d-015c94d6c30eda-31647304-fa000-17430e66d17591%22%2C%22%24device_id%22%3A%20%2217430e66d1679d-015c94d6c30eda-31647304-fa000-17430e66d17591%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%7D; _gcl_au=1.1.706805090.1598548242; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; _uetsid=5c779e7394432399f739848297b9a350; _uetvid=d421e48c4acc1f88b81573014b4fa429; _fbp=fb.1.1598548244752.1489311425; __adal_ses=*; __adal_id=c4b052ee-96b4-4643-b30e-af4af0f7460d.1598548246.1.1598548246.1598548246.2a5a85bd-5415-4275-942c-e02a8048acc2; __adal_ca=so%3Ddirect%26me%3Dnone%26ca%3Ddirect%26co%3D%28not%2520set%29%26ke%3D%28not%2520set%29; __adal_cw=1598548245533; _ga=GA1.2.436171435.1598548249; _gid=GA1.2.1493657885.1598548249; _gat=1; _gat_UA-2056847-65=1
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ClientToProxyConnection.java:183) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0x367d8cd0, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64108 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64132]: Received raw request: DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
POST /api/sts/v2/oauth/auth?client_request_id=34634696-b122-40de-b144-ab812a4b3784 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 147
AccountType: Real
X-STS-ClientTime: 2020-08-27T18:10:51
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36
X-STS-AppDomain: https://www.example.com
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-STS-GatewayAppId: 90631448-9A01-4860-9FA5-B4EBCDE5EA1D
ApplicationIdentifier: Rexample
ApplicationVersion: 268.0.1
X-DEVICE-ID: 77f281a4-7914-4417-b144-4811998c3e5b
Origin: https://www.example.com
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://www.example.com/login
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __cfduid=d722b1913f887e5df9b0c740ccef4744a1598548223; exampleLocale=en-gb; TS01047baf=01f1b32d7e1354b9f541c1bab1a81960be72277a638bce5a4865b5b1d5b2e0a9cfddddbcba0d21185b68a7d599391e972d5f065031; __cflb=02DiuEAg8LPSYevHEYiyx9rnANkoz3ETfpNySVtv8fQVr; TMIS2=9a74f2a90237486aab4dcb9d44dec14a0520aaf521b9e87e81f271264e25038c2919d29ee219162aa2ad6bdb68fbe78a86ce282ef510aa77456a3876e4e790d3fdbb0ca31af4d206c67f7b9b5fda93e11b80782ed9095c6a7d8766b4642a69785e7ba9d0a86cd98f3b42c2172a8821bbe6906b6fafc8178f0d742271591193; __cf_bm=50d03de4ce1301af67fa03c59387373fba4d8b3e-1598548241-1800-AZ39AzpjNXxDQ+qFhgfI0OYbMauZ3vXOA1MUejwqJsfE3kOEmEVmKXtsstKg5vZZ5ie/d3yHbgzM8RzzLqqSQEVnd5Vy+l06FUm5Z90kFf54ffUqgq+ywM4EOcGhdP22aetxTezQvFieWgfScPvH0SzqDmFpvrmZJmRuLvnywgcLX14Ys9uA2tMCLWSlDesiQA==; mp_dbbd7bd9566da85f012f7ca5d8c6c944_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2217430e66d1679d-015c94d6c30eda-31647304-fa000-17430e66d17591%22%2C%22%24device_id%22%3A%20%2217430e66d1679d-015c94d6c30eda-31647304-fa000-17430e66d17591%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%7D; _gcl_au=1.1.706805090.1598548242; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; _uetsid=5c779e7394432399f739848297b9a350; _uetvid=d421e48c4acc1f88b81573014b4fa429; _fbp=fb.1.1598548244752.1489311425; __adal_ses=*; __adal_id=c4b052ee-96b4-4643-b30e-af4af0f7460d.1598548246.1.1598548246.1598548246.2a5a85bd-5415-4275-942c-e02a8048acc2; __adal_ca=so%3Ddirect%26me%3Dnone%26ca%3Ddirect%26co%3D%28not%2520set%29%26ke%3D%28not%2520set%29; __adal_cw=1598548245533; _ga=GA1.2.436171435.1598548249; _gid=GA1.2.1493657885.1598548249; _gat=1; _gat_UA-2056847-65=1
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ClientToProxyConnection.java:269) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0x367d8cd0, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64108 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64132]: Ensuring that hostAndPort are available in /api/sts/v2/oauth/auth?client_request_id=34634696-b122-40de-b144-ab812a4b3784
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ClientToProxyConnection.java:281) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0x367d8cd0, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64108 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64132]: Finding ProxyToServerConnection for: www.example.com
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ClientToProxyConnection.java:331) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0x367d8cd0, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64108 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64132]: Reusing existing server connection: org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyToServerConnection@7c392fd2
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ClientToProxyConnection.java:1084) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0x367d8cd0, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64108 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64132]: Modifying request for proxy chaining
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ClientToProxyConnection.java:1088) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0x367d8cd0, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64108 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64132]: Stripped host from uri: /api/sts/v2/oauth/auth?client_request_id=34634696-b122-40de-b144-ab812a4b3784    yielding: /api/sts/v2/oauth/auth?client_request_id=34634696-b122-40de-b144-ab812a4b3784
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ClientToProxyConnection.java:1093) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0x367d8cd0, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64108 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64132]: Modifying request headers for proxying



DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ClientToProxyConnection.java:350) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0x367d8cd0, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64108 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64132]: Writing request to ProxyToServerConnection
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ProxyToServerConnection.java:316) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0xba528f83, L:/172.20.10.2:64134 - R:www.example.com/104.18.19.67:443]: Requested write of DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
POST /api/sts/v2/oauth/auth?client_request_id=34634696-b122-40de-b144-ab812a4b3784 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Length: 147
AccountType: Real
X-STS-ClientTime: 2020-08-27T18:10:51
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36
X-STS-AppDomain: https://www.example.com
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-STS-GatewayAppId: 90631448-9A01-4860-9FA5-B4EBCDE5EA1D
ApplicationIdentifier: Rexample
ApplicationVersion: 268.0.1
X-DEVICE-ID: 77f281a4-7914-4417-b144-4811998c3e5b
Origin: https://www.example.com
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://www.example.com/login
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __cfduid=d722b1913f887e5df9b0c740ccef4744a1598548223; exampleLocale=en-gb; TS01047baf=01f1b32d7e1354b9f541c1bab1a81960be72277a638bce5a4865b5b1d5b2e0a9cfddddbcba0d21185b68a7d599391e972d5f065031; __cflb=02DiuEAg8LPSYevHEYiyx9rnANkoz3ETfpNySVtv8fQVr; TMIS2=9a74f2a90237486aab4dcb9d44dec14a0520aaf521b9e87e81f271264e25038c2919d29ee219162aa2ad6bdb68fbe78a86ce282ef510aa77456a3876e4e790d3fdbb0ca31af4d206c67f7b9b5fda93e11b80782ed9095c6a7d8766b4642a69785e7ba9d0a86cd98f3b42c2172a8821bbe6906b6fafc8178f0d742271591193; __cf_bm=50d03de4ce1301af67fa03c59387373fba4d8b3e-1598548241-1800-AZ39AzpjNXxDQ+qFhgfI0OYbMauZ3vXOA1MUejwqJsfE3kOEmEVmKXtsstKg5vZZ5ie/d3yHbgzM8RzzLqqSQEVnd5Vy+l06FUm5Z90kFf54ffUqgq+ywM4EOcGhdP22aetxTezQvFieWgfScPvH0SzqDmFpvrmZJmRuLvnywgcLX14Ys9uA2tMCLWSlDesiQA==; mp_dbbd7bd9566da85f012f7ca5d8c6c944_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2217430e66d1679d-015c94d6c30eda-31647304-fa000-17430e66d17591%22%2C%22%24device_id%22%3A%20%2217430e66d1679d-015c94d6c30eda-31647304-fa000-17430e66d17591%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%7D; _gcl_au=1.1.706805090.1598548242; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; _uetsid=5c779e7394432399f739848297b9a350; _uetvid=d421e48c4acc1f88b81573014b4fa429; _fbp=fb.1.1598548244752.1489311425; __adal_ses=*; __adal_id=c4b052ee-96b4-4643-b30e-af4af0f7460d.1598548246.1.1598548246.1598548246.2a5a85bd-5415-4275-942c-e02a8048acc2; __adal_ca=so%3Ddirect%26me%3Dnone%26ca%3Ddirect%26co%3D%28not%2520set%29%26ke%3D%28not%2520set%29; __adal_cw=1598548245533; _ga=GA1.2.436171435.1598548249; _gid=GA1.2.1493657885.1598548249; _gat=1; _gat_UA-2056847-65=1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Via: 1.1 browsermobproxy
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ProxyToServerConnection.java:348) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0xba528f83, L:/172.20.10.2:64134 - R:www.example.com/104.18.19.67:443]: Using existing connection to: www.example.com/104.18.19.67:443
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ProxyConnection.java:228) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0xba528f83, L:/172.20.10.2:64134 - R:www.example.com/104.18.19.67:443]: Writing: DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
POST /api/sts/v2/oauth/auth?client_request_id=34634696-b122-40de-b144-ab812a4b3784 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Length: 147
AccountType: Real
X-STS-ClientTime: 2020-08-27T18:10:51
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36
X-STS-AppDomain: https://www.example.com
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-STS-GatewayAppId: 90631448-9A01-4860-9FA5-B4EBCDE5EA1D
ApplicationIdentifier: Rexample
ApplicationVersion: 268.0.1
X-DEVICE-ID: 77f281a4-7914-4417-b144-4811998c3e5b
Origin: https://www.example.com
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://www.example.com/login
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __cfduid=d722b1913f887e5df9b0c740ccef4744a1598548223; exampleLocale=en-gb; TS01047baf=01f1b32d7e1354b9f541c1bab1a81960be72277a638bce5a4865b5b1d5b2e0a9cfddddbcba0d21185b68a7d599391e972d5f065031; __cflb=02DiuEAg8LPSYevHEYiyx9rnANkoz3ETfpNySVtv8fQVr; TMIS2=9a74f2a90237486aab4dcb9d44dec14a0520aaf521b9e87e81f271264e25038c2919d29ee219162aa2ad6bdb68fbe78a86ce282ef510aa77456a3876e4e790d3fdbb0ca31af4d206c67f7b9b5fda93e11b80782ed9095c6a7d8766b4642a69785e7ba9d0a86cd98f3b42c2172a8821bbe6906b6fafc8178f0d742271591193; __cf_bm=50d03de4ce1301af67fa03c59387373fba4d8b3e-1598548241-1800-AZ39AzpjNXxDQ+qFhgfI0OYbMauZ3vXOA1MUejwqJsfE3kOEmEVmKXtsstKg5vZZ5ie/d3yHbgzM8RzzLqqSQEVnd5Vy+l06FUm5Z90kFf54ffUqgq+ywM4EOcGhdP22aetxTezQvFieWgfScPvH0SzqDmFpvrmZJmRuLvnywgcLX14Ys9uA2tMCLWSlDesiQA==; mp_dbbd7bd9566da85f012f7ca5d8c6c944_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2217430e66d1679d-015c94d6c30eda-31647304-fa000-17430e66d17591%22%2C%22%24device_id%22%3A%20%2217430e66d1679d-015c94d6c30eda-31647304-fa000-17430e66d17591%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%7D; _gcl_au=1.1.706805090.1598548242; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; _uetsid=5c779e7394432399f739848297b9a350; _uetvid=d421e48c4acc1f88b81573014b4fa429; _fbp=fb.1.1598548244752.1489311425; __adal_ses=*; __adal_id=c4b052ee-96b4-4643-b30e-af4af0f7460d.1598548246.1.1598548246.1598548246.2a5a85bd-5415-4275-942c-e02a8048acc2; __adal_ca=so%3Ddirect%26me%3Dnone%26ca%3Ddirect%26co%3D%28not%2520set%29%26ke%3D%28not%2520set%29; __adal_cw=1598548245533; _ga=GA1.2.436171435.1598548249; _gid=GA1.2.1493657885.1598548249; _gat=1; _gat_UA-2056847-65=1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Via: 1.1 browsermobproxy
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ProxyConnection.java:237) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0xba528f83, L:/172.20.10.2:64134 - R:www.example.com/104.18.19.67:443]: Wrote: DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
POST /api/sts/v2/oauth/auth?client_request_id=34634696-b122-40de-b144-ab812a4b3784 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Length: 147
AccountType: Real
X-STS-ClientTime: 2020-08-27T18:10:51
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36
X-STS-AppDomain: https://www.example.com
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-STS-GatewayAppId: 90631448-9A01-4860-9FA5-B4EBCDE5EA1D
ApplicationIdentifier: Rexample
ApplicationVersion: 268.0.1
X-DEVICE-ID: 77f281a4-7914-4417-b144-4811998c3e5b
Origin: https://www.example.com
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://www.example.com/login
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __cfduid=d722b1913f887e5df9b0c740ccef4744a1598548223; exampleLocale=en-gb; TS01047baf=01f1b32d7e1354b9f541c1bab1a81960be72277a638bce5a4865b5b1d5b2e0a9cfddddbcba0d21185b68a7d599391e972d5f065031; __cflb=02DiuEAg8LPSYevHEYiyx9rnANkoz3ETfpNySVtv8fQVr; TMIS2=9a74f2a90237486aab4dcb9d44dec14a0520aaf521b9e87e81f271264e25038c2919d29ee219162aa2ad6bdb68fbe78a86ce282ef510aa77456a3876e4e790d3fdbb0ca31af4d206c67f7b9b5fda93e11b80782ed9095c6a7d8766b4642a69785e7ba9d0a86cd98f3b42c2172a8821bbe6906b6fafc8178f0d742271591193; __cf_bm=50d03de4ce1301af67fa03c59387373fba4d8b3e-1598548241-1800-AZ39AzpjNXxDQ+qFhgfI0OYbMauZ3vXOA1MUejwqJsfE3kOEmEVmKXtsstKg5vZZ5ie/d3yHbgzM8RzzLqqSQEVnd5Vy+l06FUm5Z90kFf54ffUqgq+ywM4EOcGhdP22aetxTezQvFieWgfScPvH0SzqDmFpvrmZJmRuLvnywgcLX14Ys9uA2tMCLWSlDesiQA==; mp_dbbd7bd9566da85f012f7ca5d8c6c944_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2217430e66d1679d-015c94d6c30eda-31647304-fa000-17430e66d17591%22%2C%22%24device_id%22%3A%20%2217430e66d1679d-015c94d6c30eda-31647304-fa000-17430e66d17591%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%7D; _gcl_au=1.1.706805090.1598548242; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; _uetsid=5c779e7394432399f739848297b9a350; _uetvid=d421e48c4acc1f88b81573014b4fa429; _fbp=fb.1.1598548244752.1489311425; __adal_ses=*; __adal_id=c4b052ee-96b4-4643-b30e-af4af0f7460d.1598548246.1.1598548246.1598548246.2a5a85bd-5415-4275-942c-e02a8048acc2; __adal_ca=so%3Ddirect%26me%3Dnone%26ca%3Ddirect%26co%3D%28not%2520set%29%26ke%3D%28not%2520set%29; __adal_cw=1598548245533; _ga=GA1.2.436171435.1598548249; _gid=GA1.2.1493657885.1598548249; _gat=1; _gat_UA-2056847-65=1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Via: 1.1 browsermobproxy
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ProxyConnection.java:111) - (AWAITING_CHUNK) [id: 0x367d8cd0, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64108 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64132]: Reading: DefaultLastHttpContent(data: SlicedAbstractByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 147, cap: 147/147, unwrapped: UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeNoCleanerDirectByteBuf(ridx: 147, widx: 147, cap: 176)), decoderResult: success)
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ProxyToServerConnection.java:316) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0xba528f83, L:/172.20.10.2:64134 - R:www.example.com/104.18.19.67:443]: Requested write of DefaultLastHttpContent(data: SlicedAbstractByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 147, cap: 147/147, unwrapped: UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeNoCleanerDirectByteBuf(ridx: 147, widx: 147, cap: 176)), decoderResult: success)
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ProxyToServerConnection.java:319) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0xba528f83, L:/172.20.10.2:64134 - R:www.example.com/104.18.19.67:443]: Retaining reference counted message
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ProxyToServerConnection.java:348) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0xba528f83, L:/172.20.10.2:64134 - R:www.example.com/104.18.19.67:443]: Using existing connection to: www.example.com/104.18.19.67:443
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ProxyConnection.java:228) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0xba528f83, L:/172.20.10.2:64134 - R:www.example.com/104.18.19.67:443]: Writing: DefaultLastHttpContent(data: SlicedAbstractByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 147, cap: 147/147, unwrapped: UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeNoCleanerDirectByteBuf(ridx: 147, widx: 147, cap: 176)), decoderResult: success)
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ProxyConnection.java:249) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0xba528f83, L:/172.20.10.2:64134 - R:www.example.com/104.18.19.67:443]: Writing an empty buffer to signal the end of our chunked transfer
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-2] (ProxyConnection.java:237) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0xba528f83, L:/172.20.10.2:64134 - R:www.example.com/104.18.19.67:443]: Wrote: DefaultLastHttpContent(data: SlicedAbstractByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 147, cap: 147/147, unwrapped: UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeNoCleanerDirectByteBuf(ridx: 147, widx: 147, cap: 176)), decoderResult: success)
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ProxyToServerWorker-0] (ProxyConnection.java:111) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0xba528f83, L:/172.20.10.2:64134 - R:www.example.com/104.18.19.67:443]: Reading: DefaultHttpResponse(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Thu, 27 Aug 2020 17:10:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
cf-request-id: 04d27fab5700001bfece21f200000001
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 5c97688bbb9f1bfe-OSL
Content-Encoding: br
alt-svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=86400, h3-28=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
DEBUG [LittleProxy-0-ProxyToServerWorker-0] (ProxyToServerConnection.java:220) - (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0xba528f83, L:/172.20.10.2:64134 - R:www.example.com/104.18.19.67:443]: Received raw response: DefaultHttpResponse(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
```

Thank you!

---

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "false");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    
    // route Chrome requests to proxy server
    proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
    
    // to pass requests from proxy server to Fiddler Everywhere
    // InetSocketAddress inetsockaddr = new InetSocketAddress('localhost', 8866);
    // proxy.setTrustAllServers(true);
    // proxy.setChainedProxy(inetsockaddr);
    
    // start proxy server
    proxy.start(0);
    Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);
    seleniumProxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:"+ proxy.getPort());
    seleniumProxy.setSslProxy("localhost:"+ proxy.getPort());
    options.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);
    options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    options.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
    
    //options.addArguments("headless");
    //options.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");
    options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
    
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`
```

Comment: Please capture the traffic send in both setups. It might be that the site in question is protected by some bot protection and that certain changes on the request caused by Browsermob trigger the bot detection but that Fiddler than make some other changes to make it work again. Hard to tell since there are not enough information to actually reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by replacing the JDK, from OpenJDK to Oracle